# jQuery Validation Engine not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Trying to use the jQuery validation engine for 1 text field. For some reason It's not doing anything. I don't any errors to work off. If anyone see's something missing or out of place, I'd appreciate it.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

 <script src='jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery-Validation-Engine-master/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/> 

</head> 
<body>

<form id="formID" name="myForm" method="post" action="submit.action">     

     <input class="validate[required]" type="text" id="agree" name="agree"/>         
     <button type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked();">Submit Survey</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function clicked() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) {
            $("#form.id").validationEngine();               

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 </script>  
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: if someone is able to recreate my code on their machine that might be helpful as I'm wondering if there is something else wrong other than syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should initialize validationEngine like so and not in a onclick function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formID").validationEngine(); 
});
```

Comment: are you sure the validation engine script is being loaded? Are there any errors in the console window of your browser? You can go there by pressing F12 in your browser

Comment: Try changing your button to <input type="submit" value="save" />

Comment: The button wont submit the form, validation engine will validate the form on submit. That's why the button didn't work and the input did.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is wrong

change:

```
$("#form.id").validationEngine();
```

`$("#form.id")` --> refers to element with id `form` and class `id`

to:

```
$("#formID").validationEngine();
```

Read [# id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: makes sense but still nothing.

Comment: this works as well, just had to use type=submit as Jop mentioned above.